# Getting error while reading BIGNUMERIC data type from a BigQuery table using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-bigquery-connector

I have a `Dataproc` Spark job which reads data from a Big Query table. The Big Query table is having a column of type `BIGNUMERIC`. Spark is able to read from the table successfully but the problem arises when I try to get the column names from the spark DF i.e. while executing below code

```
df = spark.read.format('bigquery').load('project_id.dataset_id.table_id')
columns = df.columns
print(f'*********Columns - {columns}**********')
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

Error I get is as below:

> columns = df.columns()   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
> 939, in columns   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line
> 256, in schema   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line
> 871, in _parse_datatype_json_string   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line
> 888, in _parse_datatype_json_value   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line
> 577, in fromJson   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line
> 577, in    File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line
> 434, in fromJson   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line
> 890, in _parse_datatype_json_value   File
> "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line
> 736, in fromJson ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'google.cloud.spark'

But, if I omit the df.columns and only execute `show()` and `printSchema()` it works fine. The DF schema from `printSchema()` is as below:

```
root
|-- col1: string (nullable = true)
|-- col2: bignumeric (nullable = true)
```

I have used the `Spark - Big Query connector` to read from Big Query. Any help and possible solution is highly appreciated. Happy to provide if any additional details are needed.

Comment: i think the big query big numeric conversion to spark data frame had certain issues, which got resolved post version 0.22 . Hope the attached link might help [link] (https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/541)

Answer (score 0):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/742) talked within spark-bigquery-connector github looks match this question

Basically, BigNumeric support is provided through spark UserDefinedType, when launching your pyspark job, the required python class file need be provided through command line by '--py-files'

```
# use appropriate version for jar depending on the scala version
```

pyspark --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11-0.29.0.jar
--py-files gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-support-0.29.0.zip
--files gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-support-0.29.0.zip

or at runtime by spark.sparkContext.addPyFile

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above there are multiple issues that are there with respect to reading and writing BigNumeric values from bigquery . Alteast for reading the solution has already been mentioned in the readme file of spark-bigquery-connector.

Below is the link:- https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#bignumeric-support

Also please find the code block solution.

if the code throws ModuleNotFoundError, please add the following code before reading the BigNumeric data.

```
try:
    import pkg_resources

    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    import pkgutil

    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Also, please make sure that you have included the connector's jar in the cluster (using the connectors init action) or by using the --jars option. Also verify that gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-support-0.26.0.zip is configured in spark.submit.pyfiles or add it in runtime

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-support-0.26.0.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting version 0.31.1 of the spark bigquery connector, `BigNumeric`s are converted directly to Spark decimals

Comment: Can you provide any code snippet to read data from either table or SQL. In official page it is stated, 0.31.1 will support to read data from standard table, reading data from SQL or view is not supported yet.